# How can I find out the command line of a process that changed a specific file?

Tags: filesystem, monitoring

I am trying to find out what process is modifying my `/etc/sshd_config` file.  It happens due to a background process that runs based on periodic intervals or based on a trigger.

What I want to see is when this change happens, I should see what app and what command line was used to modify the file.

Example:

1. Start monitoring `/etc/sshd_config`
2. A process with PID 1000 modifies the file
3. I capture what the command line was for PID 1000

I tried `sudo fs_usage -w | grep sshd_config`, but that will only show me the PID of the process that modified the file.
What I need is the actual command line.  In Linux, I can get it from `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline`.  Am wondering if a similar facility exists in macOS.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you looking for a shell-level or a code-level solution?

Comment: If it’s a company computer provided by IT then they are managing it. IT Security likely wants the settings in /etc/sshd_config to be a specific configuration then it will reset whenever their interval is configured. You are asking for help to reverse engineer your companies management tooling. It’s not “your” computer if they provided it to you. If you have a business use case to change the behavior of the sssh daemon you should request that from your IT department. You may have admin rights and sudo privileges but so does the IT department and they have to configure it per security policy.

Comment: `ps` can be used to access the commandline of a running process

Comment: The tricky part is that I don't know what process is modifying the file ... so, I cannot inspect it via `ps`.  So, I almost need a notify capable program that would dump the process info.